# Is SharePoint 2010 compatible with Windows 2008 R2 Server Core?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, windows-server-core

Now that Core 2008 R2 added .net support, I wonder if it's possible to run SharePoint 2010 Web Frontends on it?

Found some articles saying you can't run it on 2008 Core (no ASP.net support), but haven't found anything about R2 Core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the SharePoint product team, the answer is no.

http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2010/01/22/operating-system-requirements-of-sharepoint-2010.aspx